# Angularjs 1.4.x $cookies not working properly only in IE 11

Tags: angularjs, cookies

`$cookies` not working properly in angularjs. using `$cookies` in a **single page application** to store true/false (stored as string).

prev version:

the code I wrote

```
$cookies.put('displayUsers', $scope.somevalue, {expires:somedatetimevalue});
```

This worked fine but after few months, cookies where not working properly.
on investigation (in chrome) I found that there were two cookies with same name `displayUsers` created for same domain but paths were different.first path was `/demo/project1` and another was `/project1` . The url `/demo` is not part of the application and such url will redirect to totally different application.
everyTime the above `$cookies.put()` method was called it never updated cookie with path `/demo/project1`. Hence its value was always false.

To fix this issue I made cookie storing part path specific which **worked fine in chrome** but not in IE.

new version:

```
$cookies.put('displayUsers', $scope.somevalue, {expires:somedatetimevalueinyears, path:'/demo/project1'});
```

**I also tried to delete the cookie before saving it, then also it didn't worked in ie.**
I checked cookie value in console but it was always false for `displayUsers` cookie using `document.cookie` stmt.
If i clear browser data along with cookies and then try, it works fine in IE till now(not sure of consistency).

What could be the possibilities of failure if we don't clear history in IE?

Also I would like to know how cookie behaves in IE in both cases (when path is specified or not).

Comment: did you include `ngCookies` as a dependency?

Comment: yup thats all included. this issue came after almost 6 months. to fix this i started storing cookies with specific path. but now its not working in ie. i have to clear history to make it work in ie

Comment: Why are you using 1.4 vs 1.5? Any particular reason? Have you tried 1.5 to see if it still doesnt work?

Comment: How does the version matter. Where there any issues reported related to cookies in 1.4.3v. I tried implementing pure javascript still the issue persist in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure the root cause of the issue.
So, to fix this issue i changed the cookie name to `'DDdisplayUsers'` and changed the path to `'/'`. This change workes in both IE and chrome.